# Ignore a property with INotifyPropertyChanged in PostSharp

Tags: c#, postsharp

When applying PostSharp's `[INotifyPropertyChanged]` attribute to a class, is there a way to force PostSharp to ignore some of the properties?

Comment: Thought there are some articles that talk about implementing a `NotifyPropertyChangedAttribute` in the context of PostSharp...

Comment: @elgonzo: PostSharp provides a NotifyPropertyChanged *attribute* that you can place on a class, and PostSharp will then automatically implement the INotifyPropertyChanged *interface* on that class for you (so you don't have to implement it yourself).

Comment: Okay, ooops, i did not know. Feel free to slap  me... :)

Comment: @Tim, I read them but saw no references to ways of skipping certain properties.

Comment: @Mau that was actually a response to elgonzo (whose post has now been deleted). Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a documentation article about [Customizing the NotifyPropertyChanged Aspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/content/inotifypropertychanged-customization).
Based on that article, you need to mark the property with `[IgnoreAutoChangeNotification]` attribute to prevent the notification from being raised for that property.